# VB comments taking up more than one line unless comment is terminated

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, specific-question, editing, formatting

In [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/31502/encapsulation-with-a-dbparameter-class), there are comments in the code, other code that was tried before, and the comment showed over multiple lines unless the comment was terminated with another apostrophe, which isn't needed in VB.

It's not a really big deal, but I figured it was worth noting that the formatting requires an extra apostrophe at the end of the comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works correctly if you specify `<!-- language: lang-vb -->` (which is what I just did), but not when you use just `<!-- language: vb -->`. I believe that for this to work, the tag [vb](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vb) (or, even better, [vb.net](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vb.net), because then it would work automatically for that question) would have to be mapped to `lang-vb`on this site.

But I'm not sure what's the protocol for doing that.

Comment: I added that comment but I had missed the `lang-` in it. thank you for correcting that for me, and pointing it out

Comment: The protocol for doing that would be a [feature-request] here that asks for it... (I just went ahead and set the default highlighting for [tag:vb.net] and [tag:vbscript] though, so you can skip protocol this time around) Note that any moderator here can set these defaults - there's an option (for mods) on the tag wiki page.